# Do something at the beginning & end of methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

Is there an easy way to do something at the beginning and end of each function in a class? I've looked into `__getattribute__`, but I don't think that I can use it in this situation?

Here's a simplified version of what I'm trying to do:

```
class Thing():
    def __init__(self):
        self.busy = False

    def func_1(self):
        if self.busy: 
            return None
        self.busy = True
          ...
        self.busy = False

    def func_2(self):
        if self.busy: 
            return None
        self.busy = True
          ...
        self.busy = False
    ...
```

Comment: Just wondering, why would you want to do that?

Comment: @abccd Do you mean why he would want to use `self.busy` like that?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant

Comment: I'm making things in `tkinter`, and I don't want mouse or keyboard input to interrupt anything

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use decorators (if you don't know them you can refer to [PEP-318](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318)):

```
def decorator(method):
    def decorated_method(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # before the method call
        if self.busy:
            return None
        self.busy = True

        # the actual method call
        result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)  

        # after the method call
        self.busy = False

        return result

    return decorated_method

class Thing():
    def __init__(self):
        self.busy = False

    @decorator
    def func_1(self):
        ...

    @decorator
    def func_2(self):
        ...
```

You might want to use [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) if you want the decorated method to "look like" the original method. The `@decorator` is just syntactic sugar, you could also apply the decorator explicitly:

```
class Thing():
    def __init__(self):
        self.busy = False

    def func_1(self):
        ...

    func_1 = decorator(func_1)  # replace "func_1" with the decorated "func_1"
```

In case you really want to apply it to all methods you can additionally use a class decorator:

```
def decorate_all_methods(cls):
    for name, method in cls.__dict__.items():
        if name.startswith('_'):  # don't decorate private functions
            continue 
        setattr(cls, name, decorator(method))
    return cls

@decorate_all_methods
class Thing():
    def __init__(self):
        self.busy = False

    def func_1(self):
        ...

    def func_2(self):
        ...
```

Comment: Shoot!, Beat me to it ;-)

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you! Also, does it have to be called `decorator`, or can it be called anything?

Comment: @diligar You can call it whatever you want. Just make sure the name you give it is meaningful.

Comment: No, it doesn't have to be called `decorator`. I just named it like that because I wasn't very imaginative.

Comment: I would only add that the decorator syntax is syntactic sugar for `some_fun = decorator(some_fun)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga You're correct. But I wasn't sure how in-depth the explanation would need to be (decorator syntax, closures, ...). Also there are several good tutorials that can explain decorators much better than I could. And as soon as one knows that this "feature" is called "decorator" one can easily find these.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to the accepted answer, if you want this decoration to only be applicable for instance methods, you could use [`__getattribute__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__).

```
class Thing(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.busy = False

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        attr = object.__getattribute__(self, name)
        if callable(attr) and not name.startswith('_') and attr.__self__ == self:
            attr = decorator(attr)

        return attr

    def func_1(self):
        # instance method will be wrapped by `decorator`
        ...

    @classmethod
    def class_func(cls):
        # class method will not be wrapped by `decorator`
        # when called using `self.`, `cls.` or `Thing.`.
        ...

    @staticmethod
    def static_func():
        # static method will not be wrapped by `decorator`
        # when called using `Thing.`.
        ...
```

- This requires `object` and will not work for old-style classes in Python 2.
- [`callable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#callable) was removed in Python 3.0, but returned in 3.2. Alternatively, `isinstance(obj, collections.Callable)` can be used.

If you'd like to wrap class methods and static methods differently, you could inherit from a custom `type` `metaclass`:

```
class Meta(type):
    def __getattribute__(*args):
        print("staticmethod or classmethod invoked")
        return type.__getattribute__(*args)


class Thing(object, metaclass=Meta):
    ...
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        attr = object.__getattribute__(self, name)
        if callable(attr) and not name.startswith('_'):
            if attr.__self__ == self:
                attr = decorator(attr)
            else:
                attr = Meta.__getattribute__(Thing, name)

        return attr
```

The above `metaclass=Meta` is Python 3 syntax. In Python 2, it must be defined as:

```
class Thing(object):
    __metaclass__ = Meta
```